# Conversion from NZMG to latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, java, gps, wgs84

I want to convert `NEW ZEALAND MAP GRID` coordinates i.e. `Northing` and `Easting` into `WGS84` coordinates i.e. `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

I have searched on internet but there is no proper explanation of how to do this, or an online  calculator to do this.

My final goal is to write a program in `C#` or `JAVA` , which will convert `NZMG` coordinates into `WGS84` coordinates.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/geodetic-datum-conversion/ ? It seems [NZGD2000 is equivalent to WGS84](http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/geodetic-datum-conversion/wgs84-nzgd2000) and there are formulas to convert NZGD1949 to NZGD2000.

Comment: post this question to GIS.Stachexchange

Comment: Can you mention some formulas ?

Comment: see here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/converting-nzmg-or-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-for-use-with-r-map-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proj4j provides this functionality:
It is one of the few universal coordinate conversions libs.
http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/

Then you have to find the proj4 string that defines the new zeal and datum description:

Depending if you need th eold or the new grid, you need the new zealand datum shift grids,+
which are included in proj4.

As a first step find exactly the name of the datum that you need:
NZGD49 or NZGD2000 ?

Answer (score 2):

Please note: This implementation does not convert with pinpoint accuracy.

Here is a c# implementation I put together for converting from NZMG to NZGD1949 and then to datum shift from NZGD1949 to NZGD2000. NZGD2000 coordinates are apparently compatible with WGS84 source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/wgs84-nzgd2000. 
I have added a 'useStaticCorrection' parameter to the datum shift method because I found my results were consistently off by approximately 40 meters in latitude - this varies depending on the input coordinates. This may be from a mistake in the logic but, as far as i can tell, it appears all correct (as by the sources referenced).

Sources: 
Constants and coefficients 

 http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/new-zealand-map-grid

Datum info.

 http://www.linz.govt.nz/regulatory/25000

NZMG -> NZGD1949 formula

http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/new-zealand-map-grid

NZ1949 -> NZGD2000 differences

 http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/nzgd1949-nzgd2000/three-seven

Equivilent of a Three parameter shift.

http://sas2.elte.hu/tg/eesti_datums_egs9.htm

//Lat / Long fudge amounts
 http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/datum-transformation-examples

```
public class Pair<T, U>
{
    public Pair()
    {
    }

    public Pair(T first, U second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public T First { get; set; }
    public U Second { get; set; }
};
```

```
using System.Numerics;

public class NZMGConverter
{
    //Constants and coefficients
    //Source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/new-zealand-map-grid
    private static Double N0 = 6023150;
    private static Double E0 = 2510000;
    private static Double NZGD1949a = 6378388;
    private static Double NZMGLatOrigin = -41;
    private static Double NZMGLongOrigin = 173;
    //some of these are unused but are included for completeness. (unused arrays are for converting from wgs84 / nzgd2000 -> nzmg).
    private static Double[] A = new Double[] { 0.6399175073, -0.1358797613, 0.0632944090, -0.0252685300, 0.0117879000, -0.0055161000, 0.0026906000, -0.0013330000, 0.0006700000, -0.0003400000 };
    private static Complex[] B = new Complex[] { new Complex(0.7557853228, 0.0), new Complex(0.249204646, 0.003371507), new Complex(-0.001541739, 0.04105856), new Complex(-0.10162907, 0.01727609), new Complex(-0.26623489, -0.36249218), new Complex(-0.6870983, -1.1651967) };
    private static Complex[] C = new Complex[] { new Complex(1.3231270439, 0.0), new Complex(-0.577245789, -0.007809598), new Complex(0.508307513, -0.112208952), new Complex(-0.15094762, 0.18200602), new Complex(1.01418179, 1.64497696), new Complex(1.9660549, 2.5127645) };
    private static Double[] D = new Double[] { 1.5627014243, 0.5185406398, -0.0333309800, -0.1052906000, -0.0368594000, 0.0073170000, 0.0122000000, 0.0039400000, -0.0013000000 };

    //Datum info.
    //Source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/regulatory/25000
    private static Double NZGD1949f = 0.003367003;
    //Double NZGD1949InverseFlattening = 297;
    private static Double NZGD1949e2 = (2 * 0.003367003) - Math.Pow(0.003367003, 2);

    private static Double NZGD2000a = 6378137;
    private static Double NZGD2000f = 0.003352811;
    //Double NZGD2000InverseFlattening = 298.2572221;
    private static Double NZGD2000e2 = (2 * 0.003352811) - Math.Pow(0.003352811, 2);

    //NZ1949 -> NZGD2000 differences
    //Source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/nzgd1949-nzgd2000/three-seven
    private static Double differenceX = 54.4;
    private static Double differenceY = -20.1;
    private static Double differenceZ = 183.1;

    //Source: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions/new-zealand-map-grid
    public static Pair<Double, Double> convertToNZGD1949(Double nzmgX, Double nzmgY)
    {
        Pair<Double, Double> result = null;

        Complex z = new Complex((nzmgY - N0) / NZGD1949a, (nzmgX - E0) / NZGD1949a);

        Complex theta0 = new Complex();
        for (int i = 0; i < C.Length; ++i) { theta0 += Complex.Multiply(C[i], Complex.Pow(z, i + 1)); }

        Double deltaLatWtheta0 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < D.Length; ++i) { deltaLatWtheta0 += D[i] * Math.Pow(theta0.Real, (i + 1)); }

        result = new Pair<double, double>();
        result.First = NZMGLatOrigin + (Math.Pow(10, 5) / 3600) * deltaLatWtheta0; //NZGD1949 lat
        result.Second = NZMGLongOrigin + 180 / Math.PI * theta0.Imaginary; //NZGD1949 long

        return result;
    }
    //Equivilent of a Three parameter shift.
    //Source: http://sas2.elte.hu/tg/eesti_datums_egs9.htm
    public static Pair<Double, Double> datumShiftNZGD1949toNZGD2000(Double nzgd1949Lat, Double nzgd1949Long, Boolean useStaticCorrection)
    {
        Pair<Double, Double> result = null;

        Double latInRaidans = nzgd1949Lat * (Math.PI / 180);
        Double lngInRaidans = nzgd1949Long * (Math.PI / 180);

        Double n = NZGD1949a / Math.Sqrt((1 - NZGD1949e2 * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(latInRaidans), 2)) * (3 / 2));
        Double m = NZGD1949a * ((1 - NZGD1949e2) / (1 - NZGD1949e2 * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(latInRaidans), 2) * (3 / 2)));

        Double difF = NZGD2000f - NZGD1949f;
        Double difA = NZGD2000a - NZGD1949a;

        Double changeInLat = (-1 * differenceX * Math.Sin(latInRaidans) * Math.Cos(lngInRaidans)
            - differenceY * Math.Sin(latInRaidans) * Math.Sin(lngInRaidans)
            + differenceZ * Math.Cos(latInRaidans) + (NZGD1949a * difF + NZGD1949f * difA) * Math.Sin(2 * latInRaidans))
            / (m * Math.Sin(1));
        Double changeInLong = (-1 * differenceX * Math.Sin(lngInRaidans) + differenceY * Math.Cos(lngInRaidans)) / (n * Math.Cos(latInRaidans) * Math.Sin(1));

        result = new Pair<Double, Double>();
        result.First = (latInRaidans + changeInLat) * (180 / Math.PI);
        result.Second = (lngInRaidans + changeInLong) * (180 / Math.PI);

        if (useStaticCorrection)
        {
            //Difference found by 3-parameter test values @ http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/datum-transformation-examples
            Double staticLatCorrection = 0.00037432;
            Double staticLongCorrection = -0.00003213;
            result.First -= staticLatCorrection;
            result.Second += staticLongCorrection;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post it has been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

NZMG to Latitude/Longitude using Swift. Thanks to DavidG's post above. Fixed 40m latitude error.

```
import Foundation
import Darwin

class NZMGConverter {

    private let easting: Double!
    private let northing: Double!
    private var z: Complex! = nil
    private let N0: Double  = 6023150; //false Northing
    private let E0: Double  = 2510000; //false Easting

    private let NZMGLatOrigin: Double  = -41;
    private let NZMGLongOrigin: Double  = 173;

    private let c: [Complex]  = [Complex(real: 1.3231270439, imag: 0.0), Complex(real: -0.577245789, imag: -0.007809598), Complex(real: 0.508307513, imag: -0.112208952), Complex(real: -0.15094762, imag: 0.18200602), Complex(real: 1.01418179, imag: 1.64497696), Complex(real: 1.9660549, imag: 2.5127645)]
    private let b: [Complex] = [Complex(real: 0.7557853228, imag: 0.0), Complex(real: 0.249204646, imag: 0.003371507), Complex(real: -0.001541739, imag: 0.04105856), Complex(real: -0.10162907, imag: 0.01727609), Complex(real: -0.26623489, imag: -0.36249218), Complex(real: -0.6870983, imag: -1.1651967)]
    private let d: [Double] = [1.5627014243, 0.5185406398, -0.0333309800, -0.1052906000, -0.0368594000, 0.0073170000, 0.0122000000, 0.0039400000, -0.0013000000]

    //Datum info.
    private let NZGD1949f: Double  = 0.003367003;
    //Double NZGD1949InverseFlattening = 297;
    private let NZGD1949e2: Double = (2 * 0.003367003) - pow(0.003367003, 2);
    private let NZGD1949a: Double  = 6378388; //Semi-major axis

    private let NZGD2000a: Double  = 6378137;
    private let NZGD2000f: Double  = 0.003352811;
    //Double NZGD2000InverseFlattening = 298.2572221;
    private let NZGD2000e2: Double  = (2 * 0.003352811) - pow(0.003352811, 2);

    //NZ1949 -> NZGD2000 differences
    private let differenceX: Double = 54.4;
    private let differenceY: Double  = -20.1;
    private let differenceZ: Double = 183.1;

    init(easting: Double, northing: Double) {

        self.easting = easting
        self.northing = northing
    }

    func nzmgToNZGD1949() -> (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

        z = Complex(real: (northing - N0) / NZGD1949a, imag: (easting - E0) / NZGD1949a)
        let theta0 = thetaZero(z)
        let theta: Complex = thetaSuccessive(theta0, i: 0)
        let latlong = calcLatLong(theta)
        print(latlong)
        return datumShift(latlong.0, longitude: latlong.1)
    }

    func thetaZero(z: Complex) -> Complex {
        var theta0 = Complex()
        for var i = 0; i < c.count; i++ {
            theta0 = theta0 + (c[i] * (z ^ (i + 1)))
            //print(theta0)
        }
        return theta0
    }

    func thetaSuccessive(theta0: Complex, i: Int) -> Complex {
        var numerator: Complex = Complex()
        var denominator: Complex = Complex()
        for var n = 1; n < b.count; n++ {
            numerator = numerator + (Complex(real: n) * b[n] * (theta0 ^ (n + 1)))
        }
        numerator = z + numerator
        for var n = 0; n < b.count; n++ {
            denominator = denominator + (Complex(real: n + 1) * b[n] * (theta0 ^ n))
        }
        let theta = numerator / denominator
        if i == 2 {
            return theta
        } else {
            return thetaSuccessive(theta, i: i + 1)
        }
    }

    func calcLatLong(theta: Complex) -> (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

        let deltaPsi = theta.real
        let deltaLambda = theta.imag
        var deltaPhi: Double = 0
        for var n = 0; n < d.count; n++ {
            deltaPhi += d[n] * pow(deltaPsi, Double(n + 1))
        }
        let lat: Double = NZMGLatOrigin + ((pow(10, 5) / 3600) * deltaPhi)
        let long: Double = NZMGLongOrigin + ((180 / M_PI) * deltaLambda)
        return (latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }

    func datumShift(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) -> (latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

        let latInRadians = latitude * (M_PI / 180)
        let lngInRadians = longitude * (M_PI / 180)

        let v = NZGD1949a / (sqrt(1 - (NZGD1949e2 * pow(sin(latInRadians), 2))))
        var x_cart = v * cos(latInRadians) * cos(lngInRadians)
        var y_cart = v * cos(latInRadians) * sin(lngInRadians)
        var z_cart = (v * (1 - NZGD1949e2)) * sin(latInRadians)
        x_cart += differenceX
        y_cart += differenceY
        z_cart += differenceZ
        print(x_cart)
        print(y_cart)
        print(z_cart)

        let p = sqrt(pow(x_cart, 2) + pow(y_cart, 2))
        let r = sqrt(pow(p, 2) + pow(z_cart, 2))
        let mu = atan((z_cart / p) * ((1 - NZGD2000f) + ((NZGD2000e2 * NZGD2000a) / r)))

        let num = (z_cart * (1 - NZGD2000f)) + (NZGD2000e2 * NZGD2000a * pow(sin(mu), 3))
        let denom = (1 - NZGD2000f) * (p - (NZGD2000e2 * NZGD2000a * pow(cos(mu), 3)))

        var lat = atan(num / denom)
        var long = atan(y_cart / x_cart)
        print(long)

        lat = (180 / M_PI) * lat
        long = 180 + (180 / M_PI) * long

        return (latitude: lat, longitude: long)

    }


}
}
```